# Rails Active Admin with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models (resources and tool_tip_infos) and I used active admin with nested resources  and to achieve this I have defined like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ToolTipInfo do
  belongs_to :resource
end
```

but if I am calling `http://abc.com/admin/resources/17/tool_tip_infos/117/edit` or `http://abc.com/admin/resources/17/tool_tip_infos/new`  then it is giving following error:

```
undefined method `resource_id' for #<Resource:0xb1073e4>
```

Apart from these two actions(new and edit), others are working as expected.

Comment: what you achieve with statement belongs_to :resource in active admin resource file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem is naming convention like we have used resources that is already used in active admin so there is some code conflicts due to the resources that's why it was not working properly.

when I was change the other name like resources to available_models then it is working fine.

Thanks.